# Jest | TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

This issue happens due to be using **mapbox-gl** in a React project.

I'm aware that there are solutions like [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3436#issuecomment-421117409) but due to me being a junior I fail to completely comprehend what I should do to solve.

I don't have any `setupTest.js` or `jest.stubs.js`

Creating them appears to do nothing for my test suites. I'm using [ftw-hourly](https://github.com/sharetribe/ftw-hourly)  for this project and I added **mapbox-gl** and **@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder** as dependencies.

Can someone guide me on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an important distinction here. This issue is happening because your tests are invoking `mapbox-gl`, but it is not because you can't test things that use `mapbox-gl`.

The issue is that you need to properly mock your dependencies so that they don't interfere with the behavior you're actually trying to test. I encourage you to read up on Jest's documentation about it's support for this: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Just to briefly state, your problem and the solution as I understand it:

1. you are currently testing a function that invokes `mapbox-gl` within it
2. when your test runner (jest) gets to this function, it invokes `mapbox-gl`
3. because you are testing an isolated function, it's likely that it does not have all the context necessary for your `mapbox-gl` invocation to work properly - thus it is throwing an error and your test is failing

So how do you solve this? By creating some stand-in logic for `mapbox-gl` so your test doesn't attempt to use the real thing.

The good news is that this is a common issue that devs run into when writing tests, and most testing tools (`jest` especially) support this concept called mocking / stubbing where you can tell `jest` "hey, instead of invoking `mapbox-gl` when this test runs, use this little stand-in function instead."

Comment: Hi, riastrad, thank you! We ended up removing these dependencies since we were using a template for a marketplace and the way jest was set we didn't really have access to stubs or mocks.
But I appreciate your reply. We ended up reaching the same conclusion and did the best we could to implement it but the template was really cooperating

Answer (score 1):

If you used Create React App to build you app you can use the setupTest.js file like documneted here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment
I had the same problem and I just added `window.URL.createObjectURL = () => {}` to setupTests.js.